# What movie are Harry and Sally watching?

Tags: when-harry-met-sally

In *When Harry met Sally*, Harry and Sally watch a movie on TV at the same time each in their own room, while on the phone.

What film is this?

Comment: Do you have a clip of the scene or some dialogue to go off of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [***Casablanca***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/) (1942) with Humphrey Bogart & Ingrid Bergman.